# How to create a "Published" and a "Submitted" date in memoir?

Tags: memoir, titles

I have tried my way through the memoir manual and various searches on the internet, but without luck, which is why I'm posting this question here, where some of you, who are really sharp at LaTeX and memoir might be able to help me out.

I have been trying to create a `\renewcommand` for a Published date and a Submitted date (without any success), both of which I want to use on the title page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,twocolumn]{memoir}
  \maketitlehooka
    \vskip -1cm%
  {\@bspredate Published: \@date \\
  Submitted: \@date \@bspostdate}

\predate{\vfill\begin{flushleft}\large}
\date{1 April 1993}
%Maybe create the other date here as well? Like \subdate and \pubdate? But I don't know how.
\postdate{\vfill\end{flushleft}}
```

I could just write in the dates, but I also need to use the Published and Submitted date else where in the article.

Comment: First up, why are you using memoir to write an article? It isn't really suited for that. Doesn't the journal offer a template for you to use?

Comment: Maybe so, but from what I can read `memoir` is the most flexible. Since I need a lot of customization, I figured `memoir` best suited my needs.

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal, you do *not* make any adjustments! It will annoy the journal editors a great deal plus they will have to make a lot if extra work making your contribution they way *they* need it to be. You are the content provider, not the designer, so be careful not to end up wasting your time.

Comment: Noted. I'm not trying to step on anyones toes. It's supposed to look like or imitate a scientific article, but it's "only" for a semester project.

Comment: That's OK. It is s just that we do see people wasting a lot if time submitting stuff to journals that takes a long time to fix, just because the author thought he knew best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but that's not how you use the title hooks. Here's a barebones example taken partially from the manual that uses `\maketitlehookd` (versions `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` put things in different places by default):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,twocolumn]{memoir}

\newcommand{\submitted}[1]{\gdef\suB{#1}}
\newcommand{\published}[1]{\gdef\puB{#1}}
\newcommand{\suB}{}
\newcommand{\puB}{}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
  \par {\centering
    Submitted: \suB\\
    Published: \puB
  \par}}
% You can then say:
\submitted{2015 12 31}
\published{\today}
\author{A Reader}
\date{}
\title{An Example, with Code}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Lorem ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```